# Snapping vertex to face during proportional edit

Tags: edit-mode, snapping

I have a human body object. I'm creating a new object that conforms to the surface of the body. I'm using "snap to face" to keep new vertices on the faces of the body object. I want to use proportional editing on the new object. Is there a way to keep all vertices attached to the faces? A plugin, perhaps?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ljMePAmmxx4

Answer (score 1):

Besides all the good suggestions that came so far, what comes closest to your question in my opinion is the **project individual** option of Blender. You need to set snapping to **snap to face** first to see the button. Then you can toggle this option on in the 3D Viewport (red square):

[image: snap individual]

Now, all translation tools, move, rotate, scale, even with proportional editing, will snap the whole selection to other faces from the view you're looking at (hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to enable snapping of course):

[image: snapping in action]

Quick animation / comparison here:

[image: snapping]

Answer (score -1):

Retopoflow for the win. It's technically a retopology tool, but its surface snapping tools allow it to do a lot more. This is where I got it.  https://cgcookiemarkets.com/all-products/retopoflow/

Comment: I wasn't trying to advertise or anything. Just telling you something that worked for me as the person who asked the question.